# vis.js Timeline how to remeber shownested option

Tags: javascript, cookies, vis.js

in the vis.js timeline there is an option to have nested groups, that expands and collaps on clicks, however if i reload the site after i have expandede some of the groups, they all reset back to collapsed state.

what i would like, was a way to set a cookie or session when i expand or collapses the group, that way i could read that session or cookie on reload and inform the script if XX group should be expandede or not.

unfortunatly i ain't that good at js. and have a hard time figuring out how to get the Group information needed.

what i have found is this code snippet

```
ItemSet.prototype._onGroupClick = function (event) {

    var group = this.groupFromTarget(event);

    if (!group || !group.nestedGroups) return;

    var groupsData = this.groupsData;
    if (this.groupsData instanceof DataView) {
      groupsData = this.groupsData.getDataSet();
    }

    group.showNested = !group.showNested;

    var nestedGroups = groupsData.get(group.nestedGroups).map(function (nestedGroup) {
      if (nestedGroup.visible == undefined) {       
        nestedGroup.visible = true;
      }
      nestedGroup.visible = !!group.showNested;
      return nestedGroup;
    });

    groupsData.update(nestedGroups);

    if (group.showNested) {
      util.removeClassName(group.dom.label, 'collapsed');
      util.addClassName(group.dom.label, 'expanded');
    } else {
      util.removeClassName(group.dom.label, 'expanded');
      var collapsedDirClassName = this.options.rtl ? 'collapsed-rtl' : 'collapsed';
      util.addClassName(group.dom.label, collapsedDirClassName);
    }
  };
```

That seams to handle the Onclick funtion that expand and collaps the group, what i don't know is how to set a cookie with the group information.

i just need to have the cookie spit out like Groupid=x ..

is there a way to do that, or am i on a wild goosechase and looking at this completely wrong?

thanks for any help

Update

After i have looked it over once more, i am certain i am the right place to make the cookie ( to remember the state of the group )

if i place a alert like this

```
 if (group.showNested) { 

    alert("something");

    util.removeClassName(group.dom.label, 'collapsed');
   util.addClassName(group.dom.label, 'expanded');
  }
```

So i can make something when i click the group to expand it, what i still can't figure out is how to get the Group id, that i need for my cookie to remember. 
so my clients can leave the site and return and it will remember what gruops where expandede and collapsed.

so any help with the Groupid or how to find it would be much appriciated.